# Collect random dots under normal distribution using R

Tags: r

I'm trying to write an R script by first plotting standard normal distribution curve and then uniformly generating dots on the plot. I want to collect all the amount of dots that come under the standard normal PDF. But when I calculate the amount, it is not the same as displayed on the plot.

Here is my code,

```
N = 20
normpdf = function(x) {
    f = (1/sqrt(2*pi))*exp(x^2/(-2))
    return(f)
}        

x = seq(-5,5,length=N)
normprobdist = normpdf(x)    
plot(x,normprobdist,type="l")
par(new=TRUE) 
u = NULL
dots_undercurve = NULL
for (i in 1:length(x)) { 
     u[i] = runif(x,0,1)
     if (u[i]<=normprobdist[i]) {
                dots_undercurve[i] = TRUE
     } 
     else {
              dots_undercurve[i] = FALSE
     }

}

sum(dots_undercurve)
plot(x,u,xaxt='n', yaxt = 'n', ann=FALSE)
```

The sum(dots_undercurve) displays different number of dots under the curve, than seen on the plot. My programming knowledge is quite bad, so please if someone could find whats wrong with my script?
Thanks

Comment: Why do you pass `x` to `runif`? It expects the number of random values to draw as the first parameter.

Comment: my mistake, I should pass 1 of course

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a `for` loop or to define the pdf yourself:

```
N <- 1e6
set.seed(42) #for reproducibility of random numbers
x <- runif(N, -5, 5)
y <- runif(N, 0, 1)

yunder <- y < dnorm(x) #which dots are under curve
sum(yunder)/N * (10 * 1) #the expected value is about 1
#[1] 0.99914

curve(dnorm, -5, 5, ylim=c(0,1))
points(x, y, col=c("red", "green")[yunder+1], pch=".")
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: hey thanx! But in my task I'm not allowed to use the inbuild distribution function dnorm :)

Comment: You could just as well use `x <- seq(-5, 5, length.out=N)`. That doesn't matter.

Comment: Not allowing you to use `dnorm` is dumb. Next, they forbid you using `exp`.

Comment: well that's kinda the point, they want us to learn some programming. So what I want to do is to calculate the probability of say P(R<X<L) and they hit to generate U(0,1) random points, calculating the ones under the curve etc.

Comment: Well, you can substitute `dnorm` in my code with your `normpdf`. They should try to teach you R programming, which means to use vectorization instead of `for` loops when possible.

Comment: Thank you alot, what if I want to generate U(0,1) in a rectangle instead of the entire plot?

Comment: I don't understand. Don't you see the rectangle of random numbers in the plot?

Comment: hahah yes i do, but no I mean instead generating a thinner rectangle, say -1 to +1 and keep the same scale ?

Comment: Just set `xlim` in `curve`. See `help("curve")`.

Answer (score 0):

Many errors here:
I thinks what you want is something like that:

```
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))
options(warn=-1)
N = 20
normpdf = function(x) {
  f = (1/sqrt(2*pi))*exp(x^2/(-2))
  return(f)
}
x = seq(-5,5,length=N)
normprobdist = normpdf(x)    
par(new=TRUE) 
u = runif(N,0,1)
dots_undercurve = NULL
for (i in 1:length(x)) { 
  if (u[i]<=normprobdist[i]) {
  dots_undercurve[i] = TRUE
} 
else {
  dots_undercurve[i] = FALSE
} 
}
sum(dots_undercurve)
plot(x,u)
lines(x,normprobdist,type="l")
```

[image]

Comment: I'd like to point out that this code is very inefficient and doesn't scale well for large `N`.

Comment: the thing is that sum(dots_undercurve) does not give the same amount of points as seen on the plot